# AppInsights equivalent of gauge

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Is there an equivalent of StatsD's gauge type of metric for Azure Application Insights?

I'm using TrackMetric method of a TelemetryClient to periodically inspect and report metrics from an Azure Function.

I'd like to see a continuous line instead of a seesaw like chart in the Metrics Explorer (difficult to reason if the value sent was 0 or if there was no value sent)

Comment: Using [Application Insights Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-analytics) [these charts](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Learn/Tutorials/Charts-and-diagrams) ara available.

Comment: so I should rather look at Azure Log Analytics queries and try to coalesce using my defined frequency of reporting values

Answer (score 1):

I used @peter-bons' suggestion and set up for an Analytics query that looks something like this:

```
customMetrics
| where name == "my_metric_count" 
| where timestamp > ago(4h)
| summarize sum(value) by bin(timestamp, 15m)
```